# Что значит 0/cover параметр background-position?

Tags: css

В коде:

```
background: url(img/tint1.png) no-repeat 50% 0/cover;
```

что значит 0/cover?

Comment: `50% 0` это background-position, `cover` это background-size. Молодым и глупым стоит знать про существование этого сайта: https://webref.ru/css/background :)

Comment: вероятно ничего. попробуйте убрать или закоментить на будущее.
если ничего не поменяется, то, возможно, ничего и не значит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы указываете в краткой записи фона свойство background-size, то его значения нужно будет записать через слеш /, чтобы отделить его от свойства background-position.
Вот почитайте : https://html5book.ru/css-background/#background

Answer (score 0):

`background: url(img/tint1.png) no-repeat 50% 0/cover;`

где:
`свойство: ссылка не-повторять позиция-Y позиция-X / размер;` (cover - заполнить)